# Git push no funciona con el factor de autenticación doble ssh

Tags: git, git-push, gitlab

Tengo habilitado el doble factor de autenticación  para proteger las  conexiones ssh ami servidor. ( publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive).

Cuando trato de hacer push a alguno de mis repositorios usando una llave ssh se mi pide que me atentifique (2fa) en repetidas ocasiones hasta que el servidor rechaza la conesion por haber superado el numero maxiomo de conexiones permitido.

Como podria evitar que se me solicite la atentificacion de doble factor (2fa) al tratar de hacer push a alguno de mis repositorios alojado en gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Si hablas de Gitlab instalado en local, y eres administrador, podrás hacerlo sin problemas.

Te pego la imagen para que veas dónde.

[image: captura de la sección de administración]

Si por el contrario, es un tema de tu repositorio, en gitlab, y no es "local", puedes desactivarlo en tu usuario haciendo:

1. Entra en tu cuenta Gitlab
2. Ve a las opciones de tu perfil
3. Ve a cuenta
4. Pulsa DESACTIVAR en la sección de 2FA.

Espero que te valga.

La documentación de gitlab [aquí](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html#disabling-2fa)

Comment: Nada me sigue fallando  las opciones que mencionas solo afectan a inicio de sesion.

Comment: Nada me sigue fallando, las opciones que mencionas solo afectan a la manera  de iniciar sesión. Cada vez que intento hacer un push desde terminal a  mi repositorio se bloquea. La única solucion que e encontrado de momento es desactivar 2fa globalmente en todo el servidor.

Comment: una pregunta, puede ser que tengas dos conexiones a la vez??¿? Es decir... la de tu local, y la del web abierta???? ;)

Comment: Si tengo varias  conexiones abiertas.

Comment: Hay un límite de conexiones maximo por usuario, deja que echo un ojo a ver donde era que no lo recuerdo